# Using an optional property in a Dispatch<SetStateAction>

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have an interface that I'm using to define standard login and signup form fields, and when I pass the setter to a child React component I am getting a compile error:

```
Dispatch<SetStateAction<{ username: string; email: string; password: string; }>>' is not assignable to type 'Dispatch<SetStateAction<loginForms>>
```

I'm building a React app, and one of the pages is your standard login page, with both login and signup forms on the same page. Login asks for username and password, while Signup asks for username, email and password. What I was trying to accomplish is for an onChange to one form blanks the other form. If I had started to sign up but remembered I had already done so, then typing in the login fields blanked the signup fields. So I'm creating the React states at the page level, and passing them all to each form component. The component `loginForm` receives the setter for the signup form in addition to its own, and vice versa.

Here is the interface for that data:

```
export interface loginForms {
  [key: string]: any;
  username: string;
  email?: string;
  password: string;
}
```

The login form doesn't have a dedicated email property, and the signup does, so that property is optional.

So I create an object that has all of the state stuff in it, so that I can efficiently prop-drill:

```
export interface loginPageStates {
  loginForm: loginForms;
  signupForm: loginForms;
  setLoginForm: Dispatch<SetStateAction<loginForms>>;
  setSignupForm: Dispatch<SetStateAction<loginForms>>;
}
```

Now we come to an example of where I get the error. I create this object to pass to the child components:

```
const stateObj: loginPageStates = {
    loginForm,
    signupForm,
    setLoginForm,
    setSignupForm,
  };
```

And this is where I get one of the compile errors. It's on the last line, "setSignupForm", and this is what I get:

```
Dispatch<SetStateAction<{ username: string; email: string; password: string; }>>' is not assignable to type 'Dispatch<SetStateAction<loginForms>>
```

I get a similar error when I pass this object to the child that is expecting to receive something of type `loginPageStates`. But the error seems to be specifically in the definition of the `Dispatch<SetStateAction>` declaration. Now, when I had the interfaces defined individually (one for login, one for signup) it all worked fine. But I have other forms on other pages, and I thought perhaps I could adjust that interface to have *all* the properties optional, so if I sent different props on different pages it can work with just the one interface. But first it's got to work here.

Any thoughts?

Comment: No you've got an error because `loginForms` has an index signature and there's index signature in the type you are assigning to `loginForms`. Just remove the index signature if you don't need it.